# Xamarin Forms Prism Problem with navigation within a listview

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

As the title indicates I have problems with navigation.
I have a page called EvaluationPage, It contains four ContentPage inside has a Grid.
On this level I have a button (FAB) and CollectionView. 
The CollectionView has Itemsource with ObservableCollection

The FAB open ReferenciaLaboralPage in mode Modal. If the form that has this page is filled out and the save button is clicked, add an item to the observable collection of the itemsource. It is done by Singleton.

The collectionview updates the new item, the item has a tap gesture that executes a command to open the page that was previously opened in modal mode and this is where it is not working. The command does run but the NavigateAsync does not display the page.

XAML EvaluacionPage

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ReferenciasPersonales}" EmptyView="No existen referencias" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                       ItemSpacing="0" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                            <Grid>
                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <pancake:PancakeView Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Letter}" TextColor="White"  />
                                </pancake:PancakeView>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Nombre}" Style="{StaticResource RobotoBold}" FontSize="16"  />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TipoReferencia}" Style="{StaticResource RobotoRegular}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Telefono}" Style="{StaticResource RobotoRegular}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TiempoConocerlo}" Style="{StaticResource RobotoRegular}" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FechaRegistro, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="1" />
                        </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>

        <pancake:PancakeView Elevation="10" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,20,22" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" Grid.Row="0">
            <pancake:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenReferenciaCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </pancake:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label Text="&#xf067;" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource IconStyleSolid}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </pancake:PancakeView>
    </Grid>
```

CODE EvaluacionPageViewModel

```
public DelegateCommand OpenReferenciaCommand => _openReferenciaCommand ?? (_openReferenciaCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowReferenciaPersonal));

async void ShowReferenciaPersonal()
        {

            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ReferenciaPersonalPage", useModalNavigation: true);
        }

// Add item to datasource
public void AddReferenciaPersonal(ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel item)
        {
            if (item.IdReferencia == 0)
            {
                ReferenciasPersonales.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                ReferenciasPersonales.Remove(ReferenciasPersonales.Where(w=>w.IdReferencia == item.IdReferencia).Single());
                ReferenciasPersonales.Add(item);
                ReferenciasPersonales = ReferenciasPersonales;
            }
        }
```

CODE ReferenciaPersonalPageViewModel

```
public class ReferenciaPersonalPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly IApiService _apiService;
        private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
        private DelegateCommand _closeCommand;
        private DelegateCommand _saveCommand;

        private string _nombre;

        private ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel _item;

        private bool _isRunning;
        private bool _isEnable;

        public ReferenciaPersonalPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IApiService apiService, IDialogService dialogService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _apiService = apiService;
            _dialogService = dialogService;
            _item = new ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel(navigationService);
        }

        public string Nombre
        {
            get => _nombre;
            set => SetProperty(ref _nombre, value);
        }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get => _isRunning;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isRunning, value);
        }

        public bool IsEnable
        {
            get => _isEnable;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isEnable, value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Commands

        public DelegateCommand CloseCommand => _closeCommand ?? (_closeCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCloseCommand));
        public DelegateCommand SaveCommand => _saveCommand ?? (_saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSaveCommand));
        #endregion

        #region Metodos
        async void ExecuteCloseCommand()
        {
            await _navigationService.GoBackAsync();
        }

        private async void ExecuteSaveCommand()
        {
            IsRunning = true;
            IsEnable = false;

            _item.Direccion = Direccion;
            _item.Nombre = Nombre;
            _item.Telefono = Telefono;
            _item.TiempoConocerlo = TiempoConocerlo;
            _item.TipoReferencia = TipoReferencia;
            _item.FechaRegistro = _item.IdReferencia > 0 ? _item.FechaRegistro : DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

            EvaluacionPageViewModel.GetInstance().AddReferenciaPersonal(_item);

            IsRunning = false;
            IsEnable = true;

            await _navigationService.GoBackAsync();

        }
        #endregion

        public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
            if (parameters.ContainsKey("item"))
            {
                _item = parameters.GetValue<ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel>("item");
                Nombre = _item.Nombre;
                Direccion = _item.Direccion;
                Telefono = _item.Telefono;
                TiempoConocerlo = _item.TiempoConocerlo;
                TipoReferencia = _item.TipoReferencia;
            }
        }
    }
```

CODE ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel

```
 public class ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel : Referencia
    {
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
        private DelegateCommand _selectedCommand;

        public ReferenciaPersonalItemViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
        }


        public DelegateCommand SelectedCommand => _selectedCommand ?? (_selectedCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowItem));

        private async void ShowItem()
        {
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ReferenciaPersonalPage", useModalNavigation: true);
        }
    }
```

> When I click on the (fab) button to open the modal the
>   NavigationUriPath before the NavigateAsync is:
>
> ```
> /MainMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/HomePage/ItineraryPage/EvaluationPage
> ```
>
> When I click on the collectionview item to open modal the
>   NavigationUriPath before the NavigateAsync is:
>
> ```
> /MainMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/HomePage/ItinerarioPage/EvaluacionPage/ReferenciaPersonalPage?useModalNavigation=true
> ```
>
> If I put the absolute path if it shows the page but shows it with a
>   navigation Bar

Comment: No error in navigation usually means error in xaml, prism doesnt throw these exceptions. Store the return value of `NavigateAsync` and check for the error

Comment: If it were an xaml problem, it should not open with the floating button that is in EvaluationPage